# Add properties file to build path of runnable jar

Tags: java, classpath, runnable, properties-file

is it possible to add to the classpath of a runnable jar file some properties file?
I tryed these solutions solutions:

1. running the executable file using the following command:

   java -cp ../prop_dir/prop1.properties;../prop_dir/prop2.properties -jar MyRunnableJar.jar
2. adding to the MANIFEST FILE (in the Class-Path section)

   ../prop_dir/prop1.properties ../prop_dir/prop1.properties

but none of them works.

The architecture of the running dir is the following

```
+
+ MyRunnableJar.jar
+ prop_dir/
   + prop1.properties
   + prop2.properties
```

Thanks so much,

Daniele

EDIT

When I execute the following line

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
```

I obtain in my console

```
MyRunnableJar.jar
```

Comment: class path expects directories / or containers of class files(jar). -cp prop_dir may work

Comment: i tryed bot -cp prop_dir and -cp prop_dir\, but none of them works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to solve this problem i used a workaround: instead of running the runnable jar i runned the main class and I added the jar to the classpath.

The command I used is the following one:

```
java -classpath .;MyRunnableJar.jar;prop_dir; my.package.MyClass
```

Answer (score 1):

should it be like this `prop_dir/prop1.properties prop_dir/prop1.properties` in manifest?

Also checkout this question: [Java -jar : access external configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232602/java-jar-access-external-configuration-file)

Comment: Could you try just `prop_dir/`, it seems file paths are not acceptable

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference the .properties file in your class file relative to the .jar file location. The classpath seperators are different for Windows (semicolon) and Unix environments
(colon).

**For windows**

java -classpath .;prop_dir; -jar Runnable.jar (In your Class file, the properties file should be accessed by relative URl from classpath say "prop_dir/prop1.properties")

**For Unix env**

java -classpath .:prop_dir: -jar Runnable.jar (In your Class file, the properties file should be accessed by relative URl from classpath say "prop_dir/prop1.properties")

Code:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: can you try this one?

Comment: Did you set the current directory in classpath and prop_dir?

Comment: I used a workaround... instead of running the runnable jar i runned the main class and I added the jar to the classpath

Comment: your code works because of java execution relative path address and not class path.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a . to Class-Path of MANIFEST.MF and placing the properties file in the same level as the runnable jar works for me.

```
java -jar MyExec.jar

MANIFEST.MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.test.MyMain
Class-Path: . lib/MyDependent1.jar lib/MyDependent2.jar
```

Code snippet to load properties file should be like

```
ResourceBundle properties = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MyExec");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put the properties file in the META-INF folder.

```
+META-INF
 +properties_dir
  +Test.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is adding properties file in jar and put that jar in classpath in MANIFEST file (under Class-Path section).

Somehow it didn't work when I pass that same jar under -cp option. Seems it always take classpath from MANIFEST file for runnable jar.

Answer (score 0):

I have a better approach to solve this

My project structure is :- [You can see there is no property file in this project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQixs.png)

```
package com.main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Run {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();           
        InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
        prop.load(stream);
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("name"));

    }

}
```

Now place the property file within the same [folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5M15H.png) where you have exported the runnable jar file.

**For this approach you don't need to create a property file in eclipse you just have to create a property file where you export the runnable jar and remember don't give the path of a property file, write only the property file name like this**

`InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");`